# Best known upper bound for the Ramsey function $R(k,x)$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

The Ramsey  function $R(k,x)$ is defined as the minimal integer $n$ such that any graph on $n$ vertices contains either a clique of size $k$ or an independent set of size $x$. [Miklós Ajtai, János Komlós and Endre Szemerédi(1980)](https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/0097316580900308) shows that $R(3,x)≤cx^2/\ln x$ and further that, for each $k$, $R(k,x)\leq c_kx^{k−1}/(\ln x)^{k−2}$, here $c_k>0$ is a constant. It is well known that $c'x^2/\ln x \leq R(3,x)\leq cx^2/\ln x$ for some $c>c'>0$.

I want to know for $k\ge 4$, is there any better upper bounds for the Ramsey function $R(k,x)$? I care more about the order of the upper bound instead of the value of $c_k$.

Comment: I think this recent improvement to the diagonal Ramsey number upper bound was a big deal: https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.09251

Comment: But I guess if you're looking at the regime of $k$ fixed and $x$ growing, that's a different question...

Comment: @SamHopkins Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the reputation to comment, but I don't think there has been any improvement on the result you mentioned. See pg 5 of this survey by Conlon, Fox and Sudakov from 2015 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.02474.pdf

Comment: No need to comment! This is a perfectly good answer!